# Partitioned Table index not working

Tags: sql, oracle, indexing, oracle11g, database-partitioning

I have a table like below :

```
CREATE TABLE MYTAB_TEST
(
  COBDATE                  NUMBER(9)            DEFAULT 0,
  SYSTEM                   VARCHAR2(3 BYTE)     DEFAULT ' ',
  BATCH_ID                 VARCHAR2(4 BYTE)     DEFAULT ' ',
  BATCH_TYPE               VARCHAR2(3 BYTE)     DEFAULT ' ',
  LOAD_TYPE                VARCHAR2(3 BYTE)     DEFAULT ' '
  )
  PARTITION BY RANGE (COBDATE)
    SUBPARTITION BY RANGE (COBDATE)
(  
  PARTITION P_POS_2014 VALUES LESS THAN (20150101)
  )
                )
  ( SUBPARTITION P_2014_JAN_01 VALUES LESS THAN (20140102)      TABLESPACE FOOTC_DATA,
    SUBPARTITION P_2014_JAN_02 VALUES LESS THAN (20140103)      TABLESPACE FOOTC_DATA,
    SUBPARTITION P_2014_JAN_03 VALUES LESS THAN (20140104)      TABLESPACE FOOTC_DATA,
    SUBPARTITION P_2014_JAN_04 VALUES LESS THAN (20140105)      TABLESPACE FOOTC_DATA,
    SUBPARTITION P_2014_JAN_05 VALUES LESS THAN (20140106)      TABLESPACE FOOTC_DATA,
    SUBPARTITION P_2014_JAN_06 VALUES LESS THAN (20140107)      TABLESPACE FOOTC_DATA,
    SUBPARTITION P_2014_JAN_07 VALUES LESS THAN (20140108)      TABLESPACE FOOTC_DATA,
    ---
    ---
    --
    so on ..

)
```

This table having per day partition.

I have created local index  for the same and  this table table having load of 1 million rows per day.
As we are running a delete for the table for a particular date its taking lots of time to complete the status 
and also checked my Delete query is not using the Index with explain plan.

created Local index H_POS_LOCAL_IDX on MYTAB_TEST(COBDATE,SYSTEM,BATCH_ID,LOAD_TYPE)

my delete query  :

```
delete from MYTAB_TEST where cobdate =20150306 and system ='M' and batch_id='N1' and batch_type='S' and load_type='S ;
```

PLAN TABLE OUTPUT :

```
Plan hash value: 822252374

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation             | Name       | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     | Pstart| Pstop |    TQ  |IN-OUT| PQ Distrib |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | DELETE STATEMENT      |            |  1880K|    23M|  1533   (1)| 00:00:19 |       |       |        |      |            |
|   1 |  DELETE               | MYTAB_TEST |       |       |            |          |       |       |        |      |            |
|   2 |   PX COORDINATOR      |            |       |       |            |          |       |       |        |      |            |
|   3 |    PX SEND QC (RANDOM)| :TQ10000   |  1880K|    23M|  1533   (1)| 00:00:19 |       |       |  Q1,00 | P->S | QC (RAND)  |
|   4 |     PX BLOCK ITERATOR |            |  1880K|    23M|  1533   (1)| 00:00:19 |    66 |    66 |  Q1,00 | PCWC |            |
|*  5 |      TABLE ACCESS FULL| MYTAB_TEST |  1880K|    23M|  1533   (1)| 00:00:19 |   432 |   432 |  Q1,00 | PCWP |            |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   5 - filter("COBDATE"=20150306 AND "SYSTEM"='M' AND "BATCH_ID"='N1' AND "LOAD_TYPE"='L')
```

Why this is not using index ? shall i implement global partition index on the table ? 
Is it because i am using the key partition column as indexed column ? not sure

Comment: why are you partitioning on year and then subpartitioning on month? Why not just partion on month? You've added a layer of abstraction for no apparent reason. Also, storing dates as numbers? {shudders} You'd be better off storing them as dates, or at least, the optimizer would be better off. As to why it's not using the index, maybe the data volumes mean that doing a fts on the subpartition will be quicker.

Comment: I have implemented per day basis partition as sub-partition(meaning 365 sub-partition for the year) and  so on for the next year ..and  as per the design i has to store the cobdate column as number datatype. could you  please elaborate more on FTS  ?on the subpartition ? @Boneist

Comment: Just from your example my impression is that values on SYSTEM,BATCH_ID,LOAD_TYPE are not very distinct (just `M`, `N1`, `S`). Maybe Bitmap Indexes (one each for SYSTEM,BATCH_ID,LOAD_TYPE) are more useful.

Comment: Does it really make a Full Table Scan? It should at least be limited to the subpartition.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the fact that you were subpartitioning on day. The point still stands; you gain *nothing* from partitioning on year and then subpartitioning on day, rather than just partitioning on day in the first place! FTS means Full Table Scan. And as @Wernfried says, (sub)partition-pruning ought to be taking place, meaning that the FTS should only be happening on that subpartition, not the entire table. You should edit your question and provide the execution plan so that we have more of a clue what you're seeing.

Comment: keep that mind: index helps only if you are searching a "few" record. if you want access a bigger set, than you should use more effective way(truncate, create-drop table, partition exchange)

Comment: why should using index? i dont think index is helping in that situtation. why are you not changing the partition with a table instead of deleting from that partition? the optimizer wont use index because of the big amount of data

Comment: its going for a FTS please have a look on the plan table output (edited in the question).@Wernfried

Comment: here i am not deleting whole data, i just want to delete data for a single date ,hence can't use truncate / create-drop table /partition exchange? .    is there any way to use truncate/partition exchange for a single partition to delete data ? @Thomas

Answer (score 0):

Your start partition and end partition is the same(423). So the partition pruning took place. `"FULL TABLE SCAN"` over single partition is probably the best solution.

How many rows (percentage) you delete from that partition?
What about:

```
delete from MYTAB_TEST subpartition(yyyy)
where cobdate =20150306 and system ='M' 
   and batch_id='N1' and batch_type='S' and load_type='S ;
```

To explicitly declare which partition should be affected? Will the exec plan change?

EDITED: [partition_extension_clause fixed](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_10002.htm#i2126073)

Comment: I am deleting round 2 million rows from that partition . i have tried with your delete code its not working .@ibre5041

Comment: you have to replace xxx and yyy with particular partition names. when deleting 2M is not worth of using index. Full scan over the partition (or partition exchange) would be the best solution

Comment: yes i have tried by replacing xxx and yyy with my partition name ,its showing ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended .but truncate is working in this case , but i want it in delete with where condition as i need to delete a particular batch file on the table. anyway thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 0):

so you want to delete about 2 millions rows and as @ibre5041 said and i said, oracle wont use index. You can use the partition exchange:

i, you loaded your table as usual , it's ok

ii, than create a "temp" table from the desired smaller dataset
/with create table as select, or insert with append hint, in parallel of course in both/

iii, after that you can exchange the subpartition with the temp table, and the subpartition is only containing the "right" data

so the delete is skipped